# Is there some way to detect 'wrong' measures in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, select, dplyr

I'm struggling on how can I remove 'wrong' measures from my dataset. I'm dealing with kind a huge table, where I have a date and the size of an equipment. It can't get bigger with use, at most it can stay the same size, so of course this problem is a measurement error.
My database is extensive and with several particular cases, which makes it impossible for me to place it here, among other business reasons... Therefore, I use an image and a part of the data as an example, but the problem is what I described above...
[image]

```
simplest_example = test = data.frame(data1 = c("20-09-2020", "15-10-2020", "13-05-2021", "20-10-2021","20-11-2021"), measure = c(5,4,3,5,2))

#as result:
#       data1 measure
#1 20-09-2020       5
#2 15-10-2020       4
#3 13-05-2021       3
#4 20-11-2021       2
```

The point is: Select the largest non-ascending sequence possible, and exclude some values that inhibit this from happening.

So I would like to ask for a suggestion, if anyone here has come across something similar, and let me know how to recommend something.

Comment: It looks like there may be some falsely low values here too. How would you want them to be handled?

Comment: And there is a subtle "natural looking" increase initially after the "blip" at position 8, where the values are slightly higher than the first few values. Are these wrong too, or would you need an algorithm that allowed such slight increases?

Comment: See anomaly detection in R: https://towardsdatascience.com/tidy-anomaly-detection-using-r-82a0c776d523

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to detect any time the variable measure is greater than the value at the previous time point? I'd create a lag column, which is just the measure column lagged by one time. Then identify when a previous measure is greater than the current measure

```
library(dplyr)
simplest_example %>% 
mutate(previous_measure = lag(measure)) %>% 
filter(previous_measure < measure)
```